# SOLR not starting with SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, sitecore, java-10, sitecore9

I have setup solr on local system. It works fine without ssl however for SSL solr gives exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

I have generated p12 and jks using commands:

```
“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\keytool.exe” -genkeypair -alias solr-ssl -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keypass secret -storepass secret -validity 9999 -keystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1 -dname “CN=localhost, OU=Organizational Unit, O=Organization, L=Location, ST=State, C=Country”
```

and

```
“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\keytool.exe” -importkeystore -srckeystore solr-ssl.keystore.jks -destkeystore solr-ssl.keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Kept secret as password for all phrases. Copied the jks and p12 file to solr-6.6.2/server/etc folder. Updated the solr.in.cmd file and uncommented these lines:

```
SET SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SET SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD=secret
SET SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE=etc/solr-ssl.keystore.jks
SET SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD=secret

SET SOLR_SSL_NEED_CLIENT_AUTH=false
SET SOLR_SSL_WANT_CLIENT_AUTH=false

SET SOLR_SSL_KEY_STORE_TYPE=JKS
SET SOLR_SSL_TRUST_STORE_TYPE=JKS
```

When I try to run with: solr -p 8984  it gives the above said exception.

Can you please help me out with the setup. Been googling but can't seem to find the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have resolved the issue. Seems like my java version was

> "1.8.0 ea"

. When I uninstalled and reinstalled the new version

> "1.8.0_171"

, solr started in https.
I also tried java version 10 and it had the same issue with solr 6.6.2